# 'GraphQLJSONObject' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof GraphQLJSONObject'?ts(2749)

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I have set up Typescript with NodeJs for my backend server. In one of the entity files, I am using `GraphQLJSONObject` from the package `graphql-type-json`.

Example:

```
import { GraphQLJSONObject } from 'graphql-type-json';

...

  @Field(() => GraphQLJSONObject, { nullable: true })
  field_name: GraphQLJSONObject; //error line
```

while compiling, I am getting an error as:

```
'GraphQLJSONObject' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof GraphQLJSONObject'?ts(2749)
```

This is happening for all the type occurrences of `GraphQLJSONObject` across the repository.

Example 2:
In the case of field resolvers. For example:

```
  async user_details(
    @Root() parent: Promise<User>,
  ): Promise<GraphQLJSONObject> { //error
    const user = await parent;
    if (user.is_super_admin) {
      return { superAdmin: user.is_super_admin };
    } else return null;
  }
```

If I add `Promise<typeof GraphQLJSONObject>` instead of `Promise<GraphQLJSONObject>` then I start getting errors:

`Type '{ superAdmin: true; }' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLScalarType'.ts(2322)`

`Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLScalarType'.ts(2322)`

How shall I fix this, Looking forward to help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Error is very self-explanatory. You should use `typeof GraphQLJSONObject` for the field type.

You can refer to this [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html)

```
@Field(() => typeof GraphQLJSONObject, { nullable: true })
field_name: typeof GraphQLJSONObject;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am also looking for support in the case of field resolvers. In example 2. How to resolve this